# Pass array object from controller to custom directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

Im trying to pass a array of objects from a angular controller to a custom directive element and iterate the object with ng-repeat, but appears the following error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

home.js:

```
home.controller("homeController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.points =[

        {
            "url": '../assets/images/concert.jpg',
            "id":1
        },
        {
            "url": '../assets/images/dance.jpg',
            "id":2
        },
        {
            "url": '../assets/images/music.jpg',
            "id":3
        },
        {
            "url": '../assets/images/jazz.jpg',
            "id":4
        },
        {
            "url": '../assets/images/violin.jpg',
            "id":5
        },
        {
            "url": '../assets/images/music.jpg',
            "id":6
        }
    ];

});
```

Shareddirectives.js:

```
var sharedDirectives = angular.module("sharedDirectives", []);


sharedDirectives.directive("interestPoints", function () {

    function link($scope, element, attributes, controller ) {

       $(element).find('#interest-points').owlCarousel({
           items : 4, //4 items above 1200px browser width
           itemsDesktop : [1200,3], //3 items between 1200px and 992px
           itemsDesktopSmall : [992,3], // betweem 992px and 768px
           itemsTablet: [850,2], //1 items between 768 and 0
           itemsMobile : [600,1] // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option

       });
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl : "../html/views/interest-points.html",
        link: link,
        scope: {
            interestPoints: '@'
        }

    };
});
```

interest-points.html:

```
<div id="interest-points" class="owl-carousel">
    <div ng-repeat="point in interestPoints" class="item">
        <img ng-src="{{point.url}}" alt="Owl Image"><h4>27<br>JUL</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

home.html:

```
<div ng-controller='homeController'>
<interest-points interest-points="{{points}}""></interest-points>
</div>
```

I tried with track by $index but the error don't appear and it don't iterate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `interestPoints: '@'` as the method of binding `interestPoints` to the scope. That actually binds only the string `{{points}}` to `interestPoints` instead of actually evaluating that expression in the parent's scope.

Use the `interestPoints: '='` as the binding method and then `interest-points="points"` to get the desired behaviour.

Related docs under the heading [Directive definition object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).

Comment: i tried with that too and then appears this error Error: Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$parse/syntax?p0=points&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7Bpoints%7D%7D&p4=points%7D%7D

Comment: @user1551211 Use `interest-points="points"` instead of `interest-points="{{points}}"`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks musically_ut it works with that but now the owl carousel don't load well because the link fires first ng-repeat... i don't know if i could do something with scope.$watch..?

Comment: @user1551211 The problem is that you should call `.owlCarousel` on the element while deep-`$watch`ing the `interestPoints` array. Otherwise, indeed, the function will be called before `ng-repeat` has had a chance to run. If you need more help with that, please post a different question.